# Facebook messaging API cURL PHP

Tags: php, curl, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to send a message to myself (as page admin since it is unpublished).
I have set the permissions on my facebook app and got the access token but i am receiving that i cannot send messages to this id as follows:

```
object(stdClass)#21 (1) {
  ["error"]=>
   object(stdClass)#20 (4) {
    ["message"]=>
    string(59) "(#100) Parameter error: You cannot send messages to this id"
    ["type"]=>
    string(14) "OAuthException"
    ["code"]=>
    int(100)
    ["fbtrace_id"]=>
    string(11) "Be4HuMv5xOZ"
  }
}
```

And here is my code:

```
   public function Sendfb()
{
    $request = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v3.3/me/messages?access_token=xxx';
    $body = array(
        'messaging_type' => 'RESPONSE',
        'recipient' => array('id' => 'xxx'),
        'message' => array('text' => 'Hello Messaging world')
    );
    $body = json_encode($body);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $request);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Content-Length: ' . strlen($body))
    );
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    $output = json_decode($output);
    curl_close($ch);
    var_dump($output);
}
```

Do i need to do something else?

Comment: why would you want to send a message to yourself, and what makes you think that is would be possible? you cannot even do that on facebook.com. or do you mean "from page to user profile"? in that case: did you send a message from your profile to the page first?

Comment: Actually is a page i manage that is sending the message to me which is possible on facebook. And i want to send it to me because the docs say that you can send only to an admin if the page is unpublished

Answer (score 0):

You can only "reply" to a message, but you cannot start a conversation with your Page. You would not have any usable ID without that anyway:

> The id must be an ID that was retrieved through the Messenger entry
>   points or through the Messenger webhooks (e.g., a person may discover
>   your business in Messenger and start a conversation from there.
>
> These IDs are page-scoped IDs (PSID). This means that the IDs are
>   unique for a given page.
>
> If you have an existing Facebook Login integration, user IDs are
>   app-scoped and will not work with the Messenger platform.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/send-api/

Comment: So you are saying that the id is not he fb user id? But an id to a conversation

Comment: how did you get the id anyway?

Comment: How can you get this id?

Comment: that´s explained in my answer :) - you get it when the user writes a message to your page. so how did YOU get the id then?

Comment: i thought that the id was the user profile id. do you have any idea on how to get the conversation id?

Comment: so how exactly did you get the user profile id? how to get the PSID is explained in my answer and in the docs. not sure what else to add, to be honest...as you can read in my answer, you have to interact with the page first, you cannot iniate a conversation with the page itself.